# How to implement, or does HTML5 / CSS3 support icon squeezing effect?

Tags: html, css

I was looking at the webpage http://www.cuttherope.net on the current Google Chrome 38.0.x and saw that there are 4 icons in the middle of the page.  When the mouse is over it, it has an icon squeezing effect: as if the icon is a pudding or jello squeezed on the side by a hand, and then bounce back to its natural size again.

I wonder how it is done: is it by HTML5 / CSS3, or how else is it done.  I saw this `div`

```
<div class="game-icon resize"></div>
```

and if I use the developer tool to set `display: none` on it, then the icon will go away and have nothing showing, so this should be the `div` showing the effect, but if I examine the computed values, I do see an icon as a background, but all the computed values do not change when the mouse is over it or out of it.  How is this done and is it part of HTML5 / CSS3's new features?

(if I disable JavaScript and reload the page, the effect still works, so apparently it is not done by JavaScript).

Comment: Damn, I'm surprised it works without that JS. On to investigate!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is part of the CSS3 features (mainly `transform` )

If you want to have a similar effect without having to manually code it, have a look at this : 
http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

You can easily animate an element simply by adding two classes to it.

Comment: @Ludwik's method `-webkit-animation` does show that effect, and I will look into `transform` next.  I used to do `transition` and wonder if it can achieve similar things, but I think `transition` will actually make the values change to different values inside of the developer tool

Answer (score 1):

Found it! Yes, it's CSS3, and specifically the `[-webkit-]animation: resize 0.2s linear;` property. Disable that one and the effect stops.

Comment: that's interesting.  If I set `-webkit-animation: resize 1s linear;` on Chrome, then I see it squeezed right away.  But `animation: resize 1s linear;` won't have effect at all

Answer (score 1):

I would guess it goes something like this:

```css
img:hover {
    -webkit-animation: squeeze 0.5s;
    animation: squeeze 0.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes squeeze{
  0%   { transform: scale(1, 1); }
  50%  { transform: scale(1.1, 0.9); }
  100% { transform: scale(1, 1); }
}

@keyframes squeeze{
  0%   { transform: scale(1, 1); }
  50%  { transform: scale(1.1, 0.9); }
  100% { transform: scale(1, 1); }
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS the other answers have pointed out

```
.resize:hover {
    -webkit-animation: resize 0.2s linear;
    animation: resize 0.2s linear;
}
```

References the following keyframe animation which is elsewhere in the CSS

```
@-webkit-keyframes resize {
    0% { -webkit-transform:scale(1, 1) }
    50% { -webkit-transform:scale(1.1, 0.9) }
    100% { -webkit-transform:scale(1, 1) }
}

@keyframes resize {
    0% { transform:scale(1, 1) }
    50% { transform:scale(1.1, 0.9) }
    100% { transform:scale(1, 1) }
}
```

The name `resize` is what links the two - it's not a keyword - you could call it `boing` and use

```
animation: boing 0.2s linear;
...
@keyframes boing {
```

Etc.

The keyframes say

- at the beginning, scale to 100% x 100%
- 50% through the animation, scale to 110% x 90%
- at the end, scale back to 100% x 100%

And the `0.2s` in the `animation` property tells it to take 0.2 seconds to do the entire animation. The animation starts as soon as the style is applied, in this case when you hover.